# How to send and receive data with socket in parallel?(python)

Tags: python, sockets, project

I've been recently doing a sort of a netcat clone, because i want ot improve my skills at this little project and also use it in ctfs, since it's much more convinient to use a tcp client u hve written yourself.Everythin kinda works, but for whatever reason if the person i'm communicating with sends me a message, i can't send an answer after this(the message sent by him appears fine). May you please point out my mistake and possibly help me with an idea on how to solve this?
Below is the source code for my project:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from scrolledtext import *    #it`s mostly the gui part, all the socket stuff is in connect(), 
import socket, threading      #send() and recv()

def connect():
    global s, reader
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    addrlbl.configure(state='disabled')
    addr = addrntr.get()
    addrntr.configure(state='disabled')
    portlbl.configure(state='disabled')
    port = portntr.get()
    portntr.configure(state='disabled')
    connbtn.configure(text='CONNECTED',state='disabled')
    msginput.configure(state='normal')
    s.connect((addr, int(port)))
    reader = threading.Thread(target=recv, daemon=False)
    reader.start()

def send(event):
    global s, reader
    msg = msginput.get()
    msginput.delete(0, tk.END)
    writero(chat, msg)
    s.sendall(msg.encode())
    reader = threading.Thread(target=recv, daemon=False)
    reader.start()

def recv():
    global s
    while True:
         data = s.recv(4096).decode()
         if not data: 
            writero(chat, '\n')
            break
         writero(chat, data)
                                      #IDEA:
def writero(chat, msg):               #our msg is sent normally
    chat.configure(state='normal')    #bot msg is sent like: --><msg>
    chat.insert('end', msg)
    chat.configure(state='disabled')

def srcopen():
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
    filepath = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Python scripts", "*.py"), ("All Files", "*.*")])
    srclabel['text'] = filepath
    if not filepath:
        return

window = tk.Tk()
chat = ScrolledText()
chat.insert('end', "Here is your conversation:")
chat.config(state='disabled')
msginput = tk.Entry(width=110)
connframe = tk.Frame(master=window, relief=tk.GROOVE)
addrlbl = tk.Label(text='Address:', master=connframe)
addrntr = tk.Entry(master=connframe)
portlbl = tk.Label(text='Port:', master=connframe) 
portntr = tk.Entry(master=connframe)
connbtn = tk.Button(text='CONNECT', master=connframe, command=connect)
srcbtn = tk.Button(text='Open script', command=srcopen)
srclabel = tk.Label(text='Script not attached...')

chat.grid(sticky = "nw", column=0, row=0)
msginput.grid(sticky="nw", column=0, row=1)
chat.configure(state='disabled')
msginput.configure(state='disabled')
connframe.grid(sticky="nw", column=1, row=0, padx=10)
addrlbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
addrntr.grid(column=0, row=1)
portlbl.grid(column=0, row=2)
portntr.grid(column=0, row=3)
connbtn.grid(column=0, row=4)
srclabel.grid(column=1, row=1)
srcbtn.grid(column = 1, row = 2)

msginput.bind('<Return>', send)

window.mainloop()
```

I tried following multiple guides(for example in the above code you can see a two-threads idea implementation) and use different methods overall, but nthing worked

Comment: Do not use the same socket from different threads. Also, you start multiple threads to read from the socket: in `connect()` and each time in `recv()`.

Comment: `recv()` is usually blocking, until at least one byte is received or the connection is closed.